# Brunel 2.3 TypeError after installation via pip

Tags: python, data-science-experience

I am using the [Brunel visualisation](https://github.com/Brunel-Visualization/Brunel) package for Python 2 on [IBM Data Science Experience](http://datascience.ibm.com/).

After I installed the latest version of `brunel` via `!pip install brunel==2.3`, I get the following error upon the first usage:

```
TypeError: Package org.brunel.util.D3Integration.getDatasetNames is not Callable
```

What can I do ?

Answer (score 2):

Brunel for Python ships client-side files as a notebook extension. As a user, you currently cannot install and enable notebook extensions in DSX. IBM pre-installs some versions of Brunel in their Python 2 and Python 3 environments. Those are the only ones you should expect to work.

As of today, IBM provides the notebook extensions for other versions of Brunel, in particular the current version 2.3. This allows users to upgrade to that version of Brunel before IBM pre-installs it. But when newer versions become available in the future, users cannot upgrade until IBM prepares the matching notebook extension, or provides a way to enable user-installed notebook extensions.

Answer (score 1):

After the installation of the latest version of `brunel` you will get this error.
A kernel restart solves the problem and you can use `brunel` again as usual.

In order to restart the kernel, on the Jupyter UI click "Restart Kernel" button.